# Navigate from instance/part/... to its type definition in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to know whether there is a shortcut that allows to navigate from a part or instance in a diagram to its type.

For example: How can I navigate from Example to MyClass?

[image]

Things I tried:

1. Traceability Window: Does not show this kind of relation.
2. Context Menu > Advanced > Set Property Type: Allows to show the particular type but I would have to remember it and manually navigate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just learned today: in the traceability window, you can click on the options (checklist looking icon at the top) and select classifiers. This makes the relationship visible! I've actually avoided using instances a lot, mainly because I was having such a hard time keeping track. Once it appears in the traceability window, you can right click on it and select switch to related element. I hope this helps. I really wish there was better documentation for Sparx...

Answer (score 2):

(for V15/below; no idea what they made it from V16 on): select it and press Ctrl-L (I now realize that this is the same as the Context menu you referred to :-/ ). That opens another browser with the classifier in focus. Now you know where. But (this is EA) once you close it you have no longer the path to navigate in the "real" browser. Sucks, but that's what we are used to in EA.

Another way would be to write a search for this:

```
SELECT CF.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, CF.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, CF.Name FROM t_object AS OB INNER JOIN t_object AS CF ON CF.EA_GUID = OB.PDATA1 where #CurrentElementID# = OB.Object_ID
```

Create a new search in the query builder and paste the above. Name it as you like. Be aware that the #-tags are case sensitive (these Sparxians know how to spoil a user's day - or night).

Select the Part and run the query. You can dbl-click or Alt-G the result line.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I marked it as the correct solution although I hope that Sparx will come up with some built-in solution in the future. Do you know whether the searches can be associated with some shortcut?

Comment: Well, AFAIK (up to V15): not possible. You could write an add-in but that's not much more pleasant than pressing Ctrl-F and choose from the drop-down. You can put searches in an MDG which allows to group them in the drop-down (they will appear at the end, not in front!). Optimization of user experience is none of Sparx' goals :-(